# When are PayPal Checkout redirect urls used

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to implement the PayPal checkout server flow described [here](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/paypal-rest-api.md) and I'm a little bit confused about the role of the redirect urls required by the [Create Payment REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_create)

With the PayPal checkout JavaScript components, I need to provide a `onAuthorize` hook in the JavaScript button initialization code like in the example on the page linked above. My understanding - and I've confirmed this in the sandbox environment - is that this callback gets called after user has successfully authorized the payment on PayPal and in this callback I'm supposed to execute the payment. This part is pretty clear and I've successfully implemented this. The confusion arises from the payload on the PayPal's Create Payment API.

This API expects a required parameter `redirect_urls` to be provided in the payload. Under this both `return_url` and `cancel_url` have to be provided. I understand from the documentation these URLs are where the user will be redirected after successfully authorizing the payment or if they cancel the payment.

In my tests in the sandbox environment, however, the user is never redirected to these redirect urls, as the "return" / "cancel" is handled by the callbacks provided to the button initialization. Now this leads to my question:

Despite this, is there any scenario where the user is redirected to these urls? What should happen if the user is redirected to these urls?

My concern is do I need to duplicate the on authorized / cancelled logic both in the JavaScript code and then upon entering the provided return urls?

Answer (score 2):

The return and cancel url were important in cases where the PayPal experience is not in context (light box ) or if you want to take them to a completely different page once they approve the payment using continue or pay now or if you are using this in a mobile app where the checkout.js won’t work

With the checkout JS integration you don’t really need to pass the url as the experience is in context if that’s what you were trying to ask.

Comment: Thank you. So, even though they are required fields, it doesn't matter if I provide bogus urls that don't work?